# Can you set up NavController with TopAppBar in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation, android-appbarlayout

I know with Navigation Component, you can easily set up your `toolbar` to work with it (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#create_a_toolbar).

You call `setupWithNavController` and it all magically happens. Then, you get a back arrow whenever you aren't at the start destination.

I am currently working with Jetpack Compose and I'm still new to it. I'm trying to see if navigation component is able to do something similar with the `TopAppBar` in a `Scaffold`.

Is there an easy way to set up the nav component with the `TopAppBar`, or do my navigation icons (back arrows) need to be done manually (call `navController.popBackStack` as the `onClick` for these icons)?

Comment: You have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

In compose, as of compose 1.0.1, at least, you must manually implement it. For a complete understanding, check out [this codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#0). People are trying to make coding as easy as possible. If it could be automatically done, what you're asking for, it would have been the recommended way in the official codelab, but it isn't. You can file a feature request though.